# Are static methods more composable?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, static

I have a case class called **Cell** and it has parameter-less methods for moving cells *up, down, left, right...*

```
 case class Cell(topLeft: Coordinate, botRight: Coordinate) {

  def up: Cell = {
    Cell(
      Coordinate(topLeft.x + 0, topLeft.y - 1)
      , Coordinate(botRight.x + 0, botRight.y - 1))
  }
}
```

It feels right that this *up* operation should be an instance method and be called like so:

```
val cell = Cell(x,y)
cell.up
```

However, if I make these operations static functions belonging to a companion object, like so,

```
object Cell{

  def up(cell: Cell): Cell = {
    Cell(
      Coordinate(cell.topLeft.x + 0, cell.topLeft.y - 1)
      , Coordinate(cell.botRight.x + 0, cell.botRight.y - 1))
  }
...
}
```

then they seem more composable. Now I can pass around *up, down, left,or right* as a parameter of type Cell => Cell. As a parameter-less instance method it is equivalent to a value and so can't be passed as a function.

See both commented lines below.

```
    private def move(move: Cell => Cell, team: Team, nucleus: Coordinate): Team = {

    val (mover, others) = team.cells.partition(_.nucleus == Some(nucleus))

    val newCell = move(mover.head)  // Works using STATIC move

    val newCell = mover.head.move  // Doesn't Work (needs .up, .down etc...)

    if(mover.nonEmpty){
      if(isValidCellState(newCell)) {
        Team(newCell :: others)
      }else{
        throw new BadMoveException("Invalid move from this position")
      }
    }else{
      throw new BadMoveException("You didn't select a cell to move")
    }
  }
```

If I want both features:

1. Ability to call functions like instance methods
2. Use the functions as parameters for other functions

It seems that I would need to define the methods statically in the companion object, but then define them in the class by referencing the static implementation

```
def up = Cell.up(this)
```

Is this bad practice, it seems a bit stinky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala makes it really easy to create lambdas for cases like this:

```
move(_.up, team, nucleus)
```

You'll notice that this is even shorter than `Cell.up`. For this reason, it seems unnecessary to also define them in the companion.

Comment: I added more code and explanation to my question. I can't use _.up because I don't know If i will be passing in up, down,left, or right.

Comment: @COOLBEANS You can pass _.up, _.down, etc. just as easily as Cell.up, Cell.down, etc. These are all functions of type `Cell => Cell`.